# js reset the variable on change in select-option menu

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have 2 arrays of data form php and using a select-option menu to get the current key for both arrays.
When the key is chosen from a select menu, i use the key to display this key data for both arrays. If the second array doesnt have the key, it should display nothing.
It works fine when both arrays have identical keys.
But when the 2nd array doesnt have the key, it shows the previous data instead of nothing.
php array is similar to:

```
$arrays['first']['*random_keys*'] = *random data*;
$arrays['second']['*random_keys*'] = *random data*;
$arrays['keys']['first'] = *list of keys*;
```

the code:

```
<select id="selector" name="selected_key" onchange="showContent();">
</select>
<div id="show_selected_option"></div>
<div id="showFirstArrayData"></div>
<div id="showSecondArrayData"></div>

<script>
//both arrays in 1 from php
const arrays = <?php echo json_encode($arrays); ?>;
//keys of first array
const keys_kaunt = <?php echo json_encode(count($arrays['keys']['first'])); ?>; 

var text = '<option></option>';
for(var i=0;i<keys_kaunt;i++)
{
    text += '<option>' + arrays['keys']['first'][i] + '</option>';
}
//show all options in select
document.getElementById("selector").innerHTML = text;

//show data
function showContent(){
    var e = document.getElementById("selector");
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
    document.getElementById("show_selected_option").value = f;

    //first array data
    var firstArrayKeys = arrays['first'][f];
    var firstKeysOutput= '';
    Object.keys(firstArrayKeys).forEach(function (key){
        firstKeysOutput += key + arrays['first'][f][key];
    });

    document.getElementById("showFirstArrayData").innerHTML = firstKeysOutput;

    //second array data
    var secondArrayKeys = arrays['second'][f];
    var secondKeysOutput= '';
    Object.keys(secondArrayKeys ).forEach(function (key){
        secondKeysOutput += key + arrays['second'][f][key];
    });

    document.getElementById("showSecondArrayData").innerHTML = secondKeysOutput;

}
        </script>
```

The quastion is how to reset the variable 'f' on changed selector. So it doesnt show the previously selected data if the 2nd array doesnt have the selected key.

---

thanks, works now. the problem was in generated innerHTML not going away, not in the variable.

Comment: Should `document.getElementById("showSecondArrayData").innerHTML = firstKeysOutput;` be `document.getElementById("showSecondArrayData").innerHTML = secondKeysOutput ;`?

Comment: ye ty, just edited

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you maybe need an if statement.
It sounds like you want to empty the input with `id="showSecondArrayData"` when `arrays['second']` does not contain the key `f`.

```
function showContent(){
    var e = document.getElementById("selector");
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
    document.getElementById("show_selected_option").value = f;

    // FIRST ARRAY code
    //

    //second array data
    if (f in arrays['second']){
        var secondArrayKeys = arrays['second'][f];
        var secondKeysOutput= '';
        Object.keys(secondArrayKeys ).forEach(function (key){
            secondKeysOutput += key + arrays['second'][f][key];
        });
        document.getElementById("showSecondArrayData").innerHTML = secondKeysOutput;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("showSecondArrayData").innerHTML = '';
    }

}
```

I'm not an expert in js, so please forgive any mistakes or not keeping with js coding standards.

Comment: the page doesnt get refreshed, so all variables stay once set. "in array" check works exactly the same :< it keeps giving the previously found value.

Comment: logic should be like: on change in 'selector', make f = ''; then look for array value. Im just really bad with js.if i do ` var f = '';
    var e = document.getElementById("selector");
    f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;` it still doesnt work

Comment: ooooh, what worked is setting  `document.getElementById("selectedTagsMedia").innerHTML = '';` to empty before calculating var f. thanks for the aim :o

Comment: I'm glad I was some kind of help! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function showContent(){
    document.getElementById("showSecondArrayData").innerHTML = '';
    var e = document.getElementById("selector");
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
    document.getElementById("show_selected_option").value = f;
}
```

did the trick, ty for the help.